# Elixir : Mnesia : What is the most concise way to update a set of value in an element?

Tags: erlang, elixir, mnesia

## Problem

Learning to use Mnesia with Elixir, I created a table with multiple function (such as read, write...). One of them is to update a set of field (size from 1 to count - 1) without changing the rest of the data, and limiting the logic to the minimum inside the mnesia transaction.

During my search, I happen to find this : [Erlang : Mnesia : Updating a single field value in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820996/erlang-mnesia-updating-a-single-field-value-in-a-row) though (code below). It is the same question but for Erlang, not for Elixir.

## Code

From what I understand, it works in Erlang as read returns a tuple which is directly set inside a record, which allows us to save specific data in the write action as they are named.

```erlang
update_a(Tab, Key, Value) ->
  fun() ->
    [P] = mnesia:wread({Tab, Key}),
    mnesia:write(P#pixel{a=Value})
  end.
```

Where, for Elixir, Even though Records exist, it will just be a tuple where you can only change data in the index, and return the full tuple to the write action.

```
Table: {table_name, id, data1, data2, data3, data4}
changes = [{2, new_val_for_data1}, {4, new_val_for_data3}]

def handle_call({:update_and_read, table, {id, changes}}, _, state) do
  {:atomic, new_object} =
    :mnesia.transaction(fn ->
      object =
        :mnesia.wread({table, id})
        |> List.first()

      ret =
        Enum.reduce(changes, object, fn {index, value}, acc ->
          acc |> Tuple.delete_at(index) |> Tuple.insert_at(index, value)
        end)

      :mnesia.write(object)
      ret
    end)

  {:reply, {:ok, new_object}, state}
end
```

## Question

Is it possible to have shorter function in Elixir (ideally, 2 lines like the one in Erlang) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can use [`Record`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Record.html) with some preliminary steps (like defining the record inside your app.)

```rb
defmodule Pixel do
  require Record
  Record.defrecord(:table_name, id: nil, data1: nil, data2: nil)
end
```

and in the module where you want to update the table

```
import Pixel

def handle_call({:update_and_read, table, {id, changes}}, _, state) do
  # changes = [data2: new_val_for_data1, ...]
  {:atomic, result} =
    :mnesia.transaction(fn ->
      case :mnesia.wread({table, id}) do
        [object] -> 
          :mnesia.write(pixel(object, changes))
          {:ok, object}
        [] -> :error
      end
    end)

  {:reply, result, state}
end
```

---

Another possibility would be to go through

```rb
changes = %{2 => new_val_for_data1, 4 => new_val_for_data3}
object
|> Tuple.to_list()
|> Enum.with_index()
|> Enum.map(fn {value, idx} -> Map.get(changes, idx, value) end)
|> List.to_tuple()
```

---

Another possibility would be to declare a macro that accepts a tuple, representing a table row, and a list of `{idx, new_value}` tuples, and changes the respective elements in-place.